# Chrome on chromebook won't remember where I left off

Tags: google-chrome, chromebook

My father recently got a chromebook (Lenovo C340) and I've helped him set up, but I can't figure out what is wrong with the browser. Every time it opens, it starts with a single homepage tab and also keeps giving that pop up to 'finish setting up your chromebook'. It does sync his bookmarks and it remembers the history and whatnot, but even though I've changed the settings to 'continue where you left off' after closing, it won't do this. It does remember this setting, though. I've completely restarted the computer but that doesn't help, neither does the removal of cookies and cache. When the browser is still open when I shut down the computer, it opens with the tabs I had open when I start the computer again. But then closing the browser and opening it brings me back to square one. I'm clueless...

Answer (score 1):

Chrome on a Chromebook is an operating system (OS) itself like Windows or MacOS. On Windows or Mac, it's just an application. So, when you close the chrome browser on ChromeOS, you are closing all the tabs, but 'Chrome' itself keeps on running in the background as that is the OS. You'll notice that when you keep a few tabs open and shut down the Chromebook, then boot it up and login, those pages will still be there which is what the 'Continue where I left off' feature is designed to do on Windows or MacOS.

Reference: https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/59786322/chrome-does-not-start-when-you-left-off?hl=en&msgid=59789936

I would prefer if Google would change the verbiage on the settings page for all Chromebooks as that option is misleading most of the normal users.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to power wash. This does a total wipe of the Chromebook.  Find it in the Settings menu.

Comment: That's quite a drastic measure. I'll consider it, thank you.

Comment: It's not as scary as it sounds.  It only takes a few minutes and your Dad's settings, bookmarks, and so on will sync once he signs back in.  Only files in Downloads will be lost.

Comment: Yeah I know that's true and it's easy. I'll see when I can do this.

Comment: That would not help. Chrome in a Chromebook is an operating system, so that's the desired behavior. Look at my answer for a bit more explanation.